# Why does running objcopy --strip-all in a rust program halves their size?

Tags: rust, filesize, objcopy

When I execute objcopy --strip-all in any rust program it halves their size. For example if I compile an normal hello world application with cargo build --release it ends with an 3 mb executable (in linux). Then when i run objcopy --strip-all on the executable i end with an 330 kb executable. Why does this happen?

I also tested this in windows with x86_64-pc-windows-gnu as my toolchain and it also lowered down the size of the executable from 4 mb to 1 mb.

In windows my toolchain is nightly 2021-07-22. In linux my toolchain is nightly 2021-07-05.

Comment: cause rust release still have debug symbol ?

Comment: Did you check how `panic!` behaves before and after stripping?

Comment: I did not try it, but it looks like in nightly there is a [`strip = "symbols"`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/72110) Cargo setting.

Answer (score 1):

When you generate a binary, the Rust compiler generates a lot of debugging information, as well as other information such as symbol names for each symbol.  Most other compilers do this as well, sometimes with an option (e.g., `-g`).  Having this data is very helpful for debugging, even if you're compiling in release mode.

What you're doing with `--strip-all` is removing all of this extra data.  In Rust, most of the data you're removing is just debugging information, and in a typical Linux distro, this data is stripped out of the binary and stored in special debug packages so it can be used if needed, but otherwise not downloaded.

This data isn't absolutely needed to run the program, so you may decide to strip it (which is usually done with the `strip` binary).  If size isn't a concern for you, keeping it to aid debugging in case of a problem may be more helpful.